# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment while running my application

Tags: java, grails, fatal-error, jvm-crash

I have the following error while running my program and can't figure out what is the solution  I also looked at all the topics with a similar error , but could not resolve my issue. Here the error:
My application is built on Groovy and  Grails version 2.0.4

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6dbc9a19, pid=5092, tid=3852

JRE version: 6.0_25-b06
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (20.0-b11 mixed mode windows-x86 )
Problematic frame:
V  [jvm.dll+0x59a19]

**Complete stack-trace**

 #
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (oops/constantPoolOop.hpp:305), pid=8184, tid=3580
#  guarantee(tag_at(which).is_klass()) failed: Corrupted constant pool
#
# JRE version: 6.0_25-b06
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (20.0-b11 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x44837800):  JavaThread "http-bio-8080-exec-10" daemon [_thread_in_vm, id=3580, stack(0x54bf0000,0x54c40000)]

Stack: [0x54bf0000,0x54c40000],  sp=0x54c3b0e0,  free space=300k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x1484aa]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1433cc]
V  [jvm.dll+0x75bd]
V  [jvm.dll+0x7b018]
V  [jvm.dll+0x52b57]
j  E__Workspace_opal_grails_app_views_lifecycle__s2PublicTraininglifecycleEdit_gsp.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+1241
j  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPageWritable.writeTo(Ljava/io/Writer;)Ljava/io/Writer;+608
j  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesTemplateRenderer.makeTemplate(Lgroovy/text/Template;Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/io/Writer;)V+290
j  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesTemplateRenderer.render(Lorg/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/servlet/mvc/GrailsWebRequest;Lorg/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/pages/GroovyPageBinding;Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/io/Writer;)V+151
j  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesTemplateRenderer$render.call(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+40
j  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.RenderTagLib$_closure10.doCall(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+53
j  sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor436.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+48

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  E__Workspace_opal_grails_app_views_lifecycle__s2PublicTraininglifecycleEdit_gsp.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+1241
j  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPageWritable.writeTo(Ljava/io/Writer;)Ljava/io/Writer;+608
j  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesTemplateRenderer.makeTemplate(Lgroovy/text/Template;Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/io/Writer;)V+290
j  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesTemplateRenderer.render(Lorg/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/servlet/mvc/GrailsWebRequest;Lorg/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/pages/GroovyPageBinding;Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/io/Writer;)V+151
j  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesTemplateRenderer$render.call(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+40
j  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.RenderTagLib$_closure10.doCall(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+53
j  sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor436.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+48
J  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
j  groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;ZZ)Ljava/lang/Object;+1036
J  groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;ZZ)Ljava/lang/Object;
j  groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+10
j  groovy.lang.Closure.call([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+8
j  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPage.invokeTag(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/util/Map;I)V+390
j  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPage$invokeTag.callCurrent(Lgroovy/lang/GroovyObject;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+43
j  E__Workspace_opal_grails_app_views_publicTraining__form_gsp.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+13582
j  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPageWritable.writeTo(Ljava/io/Writer;)Ljava/io/Writer;+608
j  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesTemplateRenderer.makeTemplate(Lgroovy/text/Template;Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/io/Writer;)V+290
j  com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
j  groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;ZZ)Ljava/lang/Object;+1036
J  groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;ZZ)Ljava/lang/Object;
j  groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+10
j  groovy.lang.Closure.call([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+8
j  groovy.lang.Closure.call()Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.GroovyPageTagBody.executeClosure(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+27
j  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.GroovyPageTagBody.captureClosureOutput(Ljava/lang/Object;Z)Ljava/lang/Object;+93
j  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.GroovyPageTagBody.call()Ljava/lang/Object;+3
j  java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+12
j  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.FormTagLib$_closure9.doCall(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+1156
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
J  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
j  groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;ZZ)Ljava/lang/Object;+1036
J  groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;ZZ)Ljava/lang/Object;
j  groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+10
j  groovy.lang.Closure.call([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+8
j  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPage.invokeTag(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/util/Map;I)V+390
j  sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor343.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+220
J  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
j  groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;ZZ)Ljava/lang/Object;+1036
J  groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;ZZ)Ljava/lang/Object;
j  groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+10
j  groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;ZZ)Ljava/lang/Object;+504
J  groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;ZZ)Ljava/lang/Object;
j  groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+10
j  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(Lgroovy/lang/GroovyObject;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+18
j  E__Workspace_opal_grails_app_views_publicTraining_edit_gsp$_run_closure2.doCall()Ljava/lang/Object;+1555
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
J  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
j  groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;ZZ)Ljava/lang/Object;+1036
J  groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;ZZ)Ljava/lang/Object;+1036
J  groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;ZZ)Ljava/lang/Object;
j  groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+10
j  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.SitemeshTagLib$_closure3.doCall(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+23
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
J  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
j  groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;ZZ)Ljava/lang/Object;+1036
J  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+101
j  org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+65
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+151
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+101
j  org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+65
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+151
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+101
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Lorg/apache/catalina/core/ApplicationDispatcher$State;)V+393
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Lorg/apache/catalina/core/ApplicationDispatcher$State;)V+98
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+338
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+55
j  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Lorg/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/mapping/UrlMappingInfo;Ljava/util/Map;Z)Ljava/lang/String;+56
j  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Lorg/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/mapping/UrlMappingInfo;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljava/lang/String;+5
j  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Lorg/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/mapping/UrlMappingInfo;)Ljava/lang/String;+6
j  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter.UrlMappingsFilter.doFilterInternal(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+644
j  org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+90
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+151
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+101
j  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.obtainContent(Lcom/opensymphony/sitemesh/ContentProcessor;Lcom/opensymphony/sitemesh/webapp/SiteMeshWebAppContext;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)Lcom/opensymphony/sitemesh/Content;+52
j  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+126
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+151
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+101
j  javax.servlet.FilterChain$doFilter.call(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+22
j  org.grails.plugin.resource.DevModeSanityFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+166
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+151
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+101
j  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+70
j  org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(Lorg/springframework/security/web/FilterInvocation;)V+87
j  org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+15
j  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+196
j  org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+17
j  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+196
j  org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+148
j  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+196
j  org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+309
j  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+196
j  org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+17
j  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+196
j  org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+28
j  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+61
j  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+196
j  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+193
j  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+196
j  org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+165
j  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+196
j  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+148
j  org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(Ljavax/servlet/Filter;Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+5
j  org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+71
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+151
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+101
j  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+98
j  org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+90
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+151
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+101
j  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+63
j  org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+90
j  
---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
=>0x44837800 JavaThread "http-bio-8080-exec-10" daemon [_thread_in_vm, id=3580, stack(0x54bf0000,0x54c40000)]
  0x5362d800 JavaThread "http-bio-8080-exec-9" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5800, stack(0x54ba0000,0x54bf0000)]
  0x4812b400 JavaThread "http-bio-8080-exec-8" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=620, stack(0x54b50000,0x54ba0000)]
  0x4465d800 JavaThread "http-bio-8080-exec-7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7132, stack(0x54b00000,0x54b50000)]
  0x45005400 JavaThread "http-bio-8080-exec-6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6928, stack(0x54ab0000,0x54b00000)]
  0x47847800 JavaThread "http-bio-8080-exec-5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5920, stack(0x54a60000,0x54ab0000)]
  0x45e6c400 JavaThread "http-bio-8080-exec-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6184, stack(0x54a10000,0x54a60000)]
  0x45811400 JavaThread "http-bio-8080-exec-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7420, stack(0x549c0000,0x54a10000)]
  0x44767400 JavaThread "http-bio-8080-exec-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7432, stack(0x545f0000,0x54640000)]
  0x46a9d400 JavaThread "http-bio-8080-exec-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1944, stack(0x54500000,0x54550000)]
  0x4cc90400 JavaThread "Thread-11" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2744, stack(0x54970000,0x549c0000)]
  0x494b4c00 JavaThread "http-bio-8080-AsyncTimeout" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6940, stack(0x54920000,0x54970000)]
  0x46080400 JavaThread "http-bio-8080-Acceptor-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=7116, stack(0x548d0000,0x54920000)]
  0x46081800 JavaThread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Tomcat]]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6324, stack(0x54880000,0x548d0000)]
  0x45a58c00 JavaThread "com.springpeople.opal.Requestmap.data" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=596, stack(0x54830000,0x54880000)]
  0x47752400 JavaThread "org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.orm.auditable.AuditLogEvent.data" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3628, stack(0x547e0000,0x54830000)]
  0x44643400 JavaThread "com.springpeople.opal.Role.data" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7136, stack(0x54790000,0x547e0000)]
  0x47bb1400 JavaThread "net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager@d3e679" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7568, stack(0x54740000,0x54790000)]
  0x45c14c00 JavaThread "pool-4-thread-5" [_thread_blocked, id=6016, stack(0x546f0000,0x54740000)]
  0x466b9400 JavaThread "pool-4-thread-4" [_thread_blocked, id=7796, stack(0x546a0000,0x546f0000)]
  0x4598cc00 JavaThread "pool-4-thread-3" [_thread_blocked, id=7036, stack(0x54650000,0x546a0000)]
  0x44945c00 JavaThread "pool-4-thread-2" [_thread_blocked, id=4476, stack(0x545a0000,0x545f0000)]
  0x455b4c00 JavaThread "pool-4-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=4100, stack(0x54550000,0x545a0000)]
  0x50d6c400 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-5" [_thread_blocked, id=7928, stack(0x544b0000,0x54500000)]
  0x44f9cc00 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-4" [_thread_blocked, id=7260, stack(0x54460000,0x544b0000)]
  0x455ccc00 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-3" [_thread_blocked, id=6596, stack(0x54410000,0x54460000)]
  0x46697400 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-2" [_thread_blocked, id=8132, stack(0x543c0000,0x54410000)]
  0x45a37c00 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=1580, stack(0x54370000,0x543c0000)]
  0x45a60c00 JavaThread "FileSystemWatcher: files=#411 cl=java.net.URLClassLoader@388c74" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8156, stack(0x54320000,0x54370000)]
  0x455f7c00 JavaThread "FileSystemWatcher: files=#2 cl=org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsRootLoader@bf2d5e" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6792, stack(0x542d0000,0x54320000)]
  0x4663f400 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=7532, stack(0x54280000,0x542d0000)]
  0x46ecb800 JavaThread "Synchronizer (Spring UAA/1.0.1)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7636, stack(0x54230000,0x54280000)]
  0x43f58000 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2444, stack(0x44430000,0x44480000)]
  0x43f5d800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7048, stack(0x443e0000,0x44430000)]
  0x4419a400 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4968, stack(0x44390000,0x443e0000)]
  0x43f1dc00 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6332, stack(0x44140000,0x44190000)]
  0x43f1c400 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4840, stack(0x440f0000,0x44140000)]
  0x43f0e400 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7184, stack(0x440a0000,0x440f0000)]
  0x43f09c00 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5716, stack(0x44050000,0x440a0000)]
  0x002b8000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_blocked, id=7204, stack(0x008c0000,0x00910000)]

Other Threads:
  0x43f05c00 VMThread [stack: 0x44000000,0x44050000] [id=2736]
  0x43f5a000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x44480000,0x444d0000] [id=7560]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 229952K, used 135835K [0x33ad0000, 0x43ad0000, 0x43ad0000)
  eden space 197568K, 61% used [0x33ad0000,0x3b152438,0x3fbc0000)
  from space 32384K, 44% used [0x41b30000,0x42954a78,0x43ad0000)
  to   space 32192K, 0% used [0x3fbc0000,0x3fbc0000,0x41b30000)
 PSOldGen        total 524288K, used 213382K [0x13ad0000, 0x33ad0000, 0x33ad0000)
  object space 524288K, 40% used [0x13ad0000,0x20b31830,0x33ad0000)
 PSPermGen       total 262144K, used 85837K [0x03ad0000, 0x13ad0000, 0x13ad0000)
  object space 262144K, 32% used [0x03ad0000,0x08ea3650,0x13ad0000)

Code Cache  [0x00a10000, 0x01208000, 0x03a10000)
 total_blobs=2191 nmethods=1772 adapters=372 free_code_cache=42062016 largest_free_block=14336

Dynamic libraries:
0x00400000 - 0x00424000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\java.exe
0x7c900000 - 0x7c9b2000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
0x7c800000 - 0x7c8f6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll
0x77dd0000 - 0x77e6b000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x77e70000 - 0x77f03000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x77fe0000 - 0x77ff1000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\Secur32.dll
0x7c340000 - 0x7c396000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\bin\msvcr71.dll
0x6db70000 - 0x6dfc8000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x7e410000 - 0x7e4a1000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
0x77f10000 - 0x77f59000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll
0x76b40000 - 0x76b6d000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINMM.dll
0x76390000 - 0x763ad000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x6d850000 - 0x6d85c000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x6d3d0000 - 0x6d3ef000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\bin\java.dll
0x76bf0000 - 0x76bfb000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x6d370000 - 0x6d38a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\bin\instrument.dll
0x6d890000 - 0x6d89f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x68000000 - 0x68036000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x77c10000 - 0x77c68000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x769c0000 - 0x76a74000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USERENV.dll
0x5b860000 - 0x5b8b5000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\netapi32.dll
0x6d6b0000 - 0x6d6c3000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\bin\net.dll
0x71ab0000 - 0x71ac7000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x71aa0000 - 0x71aa8000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2HELP.dll
0x71a50000 - 0x71a8f000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\mswsock.dll
0x76f20000 - 0x76f47000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x76d60000 - 0x76d79000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\iphlpapi.dll


VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xmx768M -Xms768M -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -javaagent:E:/springsource/grails-2.0.4/bin/../lib/com.springsource.springloaded/springloaded-core/jars/springloaded-core-1.0.5.jar -Xverify:none -Dspringloaded=profile=grails -Dprogram.name= -Dgrails.home=E:\springsource\grails-2.0.4\bin\.. -Dgrails.version=2.0.4 -Dbase.dir=. -Dtools.jar=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\lib\tools.jar -Dgroovy.starter.conf=E:\springsource\grails-2.0.4\bin\..\conf\groovy-starter.conf 
java_command: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter --main org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner --conf E:\springsource\grails-2.0.4\bin\..\conf\groovy-starter.conf --classpath   run-app
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25
PATH=C:\Program Files\PC Connectivity Solution\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin;3.25003E+221RAILS_HOME\bin;E:\springsource\grails-2.0.4\bin;C:\xampplite\php;C:\xampplite\htdocs\cakephp\app\Console;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\xampp\htdocs\testApp\lib\Cake\Console;E:\program FilesGroovy-1.8.6\bin;E:\jboss\apache-ant-1.8.4/bin
USERNAME=Hussain
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows XP Build 2600 Service Pack 3

CPU:total 2 (2 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 23 stepping 10, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1

Memory: 4k page, physical 3072196k(382656k free), swap 5003920k(864692k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (20.0-b11) for windows-x86 JRE (1.6.0_25-b06), built on Apr 14 2011 00:56:15 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 7.1 (VS2003)

time: Fri Jul 27 11:35:15 2012
elapsed time: 139 seconds
```

I have no idea what is wrong here. how to solve this problem?

Comment: Showing the error is a good first step, but what code is causing the problem? Can you perhaps provide more information that could help solve the problem?

Comment: i was editing a simple gsp page which renders the model value.

Comment: "I did something and my computer crashes". Now try to tell me what I did wrong... Just notice that we cannot help you without the code which raised this fatal error, that's just non-sense !

Comment: @NNzz I have the same problem and the code causing it is test written in Spock 0.7 for generating some report data to the Excel file using Apache POI. Now I have 7 of those tests, based on the same instructions and way of checking things. And suddenly checking one of the cells crashes JVM. I had 3 types of this crashes with 3 different JVM errors - the one above, but also e.g. `guarantee(result == EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION) failed: Unexpected result from topLevelExceptionFilter`

The code itself, that we write on the high level, seems to have nothing to do with those errors.
@maaz

Answer (score 2):

This means that the JVM process has tried to access a memory position the OS has not given access to.

I don't think you can get this error from using pure Java, I believe it is either:

- A error in some JNI library you have loaded.
- Excluding that, the JVM executable has a bug, or simply it has been corrupted. Reinstall / upgrade to a newer version.

Comment: I have updated java and JRE to current version but still the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you solved this problem another way, but this is the ONLY hit I got from the internet when researching the same error.

What I found:  Also using Grails 2.0.4, and the "grails run-app" command I was able to create this error from an arbitrary gsp page.  Unfortunately, it's not on a machine where I can reinstall the jre, so some other thing must be causing it!

I'm not expert, but I suspect the root is in jetty (the webserver that comes with grails).  I ran a "grails war" and then ran the war from jboss and... magic!  It worked fine.

Comment: My application crashes in a similar way also when running it on a VMWare tc server (delivered with STS Tool Suite), so I doubt this is the onle reason. For me this error happens when I send a lot of HTTP request from the server using GPars and HttpBuilder. I suspect the problem is in one of those libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case some else runs into same error in the future I believe this failure may be related to the perm gen memory filling up. I have found a number of hs_err_pid*.log files with this error in them and the majority of them indicate that perm gen is full. It may be different in your case because the web server may have done more some cleanups in perm gen but this pool was allocated near the end of the list. Anyways increasing MaxPermGen cleared up this issue for me, YMMV.

```
PSPermGen       total 83968K, used 83967K [0x00000005fbc00000,
 0x0000000600e00000, 0x0000000600e00000)   object space 83968K, 99%
 used [0x00000005fbc00000,0x0000000600dffd70,0x0000000600e00000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error on VMWares. It definitely has to do with the memory. I got the same error as well.

PSPermGen       total 83968K, used 83967K [0x00000000dae00000, 0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e0000000)

Solution : increase PermGen  (-XX:MaxPermSize=512M)

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning the application solved my problem. 
To clean execute "grails clean".